# Is it possible to access custom object calendars through apex query? (Lightning experience)

Tags: apex, soql, custom-object, lightning-experience

Lightning Experience allows you to create custom calendars based on standard and custom objects with a name and date field of your choosing.

I am wondering if it is possible to access these custom calendars through a query in apex to grab their setup information, and if it is, how do you query them?

Answer (score 0):

CalendarView is the one you're looking for. Just use that as a Sobject type during the creation and SOQL query